# In javascript, is it possible for me to return the element of any DOM element I'm hovering over?

Tags: javascript, html, hover, event-listener

For example, if I have an HTML snippet like so:

```
<body>
    <div id="1">
        <span class="title">I'm a title!</span>
    </div>
    <div id="2">I'm the first element!</div>
    <div id="3">I'm the first element!</div>
<body>
```

Obviously, if I wanted to get a specific element, say the div with id of 1, I could do something like

```
document.getElementById("1").addEventListener("mouseover", () => console.log("in div 1!"), false);
```

and that would output `in div 1!` whenever I hovered over it. But is there some javascript I can have that apply to every single element in `body`? To basically write some function like, `getElementUserIsHoveringOver()`?

I don't think `addEventListener` works on `HTMLCollections`, which was my only idea.

Answer (score 5):

`mouseover` bubbles, so if you attach a listener to the `<body>`, you can watch for events and log the `event.target`:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

```html
<div id="1">
    <span class="title">I'm a title!</span>
</div>
<div id="2">I'm the first element!</div>
<div id="3">I'm the second element!</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking to learn! Thank you so much!